# Submitted app in Appstore and Play. Background location different policy for the two stores

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Did anyone of you submitted an app to Play and AppStore which uses background location.
I have noted that Appstore in their guidelines: Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
write - A custom message appears before the permission request, and to proceed users press a “Accept” button. Use words like "Continue" or "Next" on the button instead.
And Play in their policy, as here in the short video https://youtu.be/b0I1Xq_iSK4 - want us to write Accept on the same button.

So a question for those of you who got the app approved. What did you write?

Rejected in Appstore and Play

Comment: Can you clarify which clause in 5.1.1. you are referring to?

Comment: 5.1.2 Data Use and Sharing - further investigation sent me to this
location button  https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/privacy#Location-button
and tracking: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/privacy#Pre-alert-screens-windows-or-views

Comment: There is nothing in 5.1.2 that covers location permissions either. The human interface guidelines are just that; guidelines on best practice but they aren't binding in any way. The only permission request that must be shown is the operating system prompt that is shown when your app requests location permission.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic